# Data crawling websites using cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I got trouble with crawling data from website. I cant get the tag `<tbody>` of table , and then i cant not get the content text of tag `<tr>` and `<td>`. I used cheerio to crawling data. Please help me. Here are the codes below:

```
const cheerio= require('cheerio');
const request= require('request-promise');

    request('https://liveboard.cafef.vn/',(error,response,html) => {
        if(!error && response.statusCode==200)
        {
            const $=cheerio.load(html);
            const tab=$('#myTable')
            const tr=tab.find('tbody').find('tr')
               
               for (var j=0; j<tr.length;j++ )
               {
                    const contTr=$(tr[j])
                    console.log(contTr.text().trim())
                    const td=contTr.find('td')
                    for (var i=0;i<td.length;i++)
                    {
                       const contTd=$(td[i])
                        console.log(contTd.text())
                    }  
               }
          }
    else
    {
     new Error(error)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look into `view-source:https://liveboard.cafef.vn/` you will see that all `tbody` tags are emty. They are filled by JavaScript. `cheerio` does not run JavaScript, it just parses the static source HTML. You need something like https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/ — a headless browser manipulation library that runs JavaScript and helps to scrape full-fledged pages.

Comment: Thank you for helping me . I will try your method to scrape data